# Spring Boot - Return an empty array of objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to perform a simple GET and when I run and insert the directory it returns an empty array:

This is my class:

```java
public class Movie {
  String directory;
  String name;
  boolean isPlaying;
  int watchedCounter;

  public Movie(String directory, String name, boolean isPlaying, int watchedCounter) {
    this.directory = directory;
    this.name = name;
    this.isPlaying = isPlaying;
    this.watchedCounter = watchedCounter;
  }
}
```

My Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/vod")
public class MovieConroller {
  private final MovieService movieService;

  @Autowired
  public MovieConroller(MovieService movieService) {
    this.movieService = movieService;
  }

  @GetMapping
  public List < Movie > getMovies() {
    return movieService.getMovies();
  }
}
```

My Service:

```java
@Service
public class MovieService {
  public List < Movie > getMovies() {
    List < Movie > movies = new ArrayList < > ();
    movies.add(new Movie("home", "film.avi", true, 0));
    movies.add(new Movie("house", "fil2m.avi", false, 1));
    return movies;
  }
}
```

And this is my application properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=ad
spring.data.mongodb.password=pas
spring.data.mongodb.database=mov
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
```

The URL : `http://localhost:8080/api/vod`
Result : `[{}{}]`

Can someone please assists?
Regards

Comment: Do you have `getters` and `setters` into `Movie` class?

Comment: Hi, no. This is the real project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the lack of `getters` and `setters`.

Usually it thrown an error, but using `spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false` it returns `{}` because can't serialize the objects.

If you add `getters` and `setters` it will return the list with objects filled.